# Regex Replace Unique Using VB6

Tags: regex, vb6

How do you replace using regex?

For example. the String is `D + WIDTH / 2`

If I try to replace D into 1 the output is `1 + WI1TH / /2`.

How do you replace the D only, and exclude the D of WIDTH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\bD\b
```

Should do it for you.
\b is for word boundary

Comment: Title says VB6. Tag says VB6. No edits to either. Answer is VB.NET. Accepted. Lol.